# jqgrid paging buttons not enabled

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I don't see what is wrong with the code for the paging buttons not to be displayed

[image: initial loading of empty grid buttons show]

[image: grid loaded displaying 1 of 4 records, buttons not showing]

```
function LoadAgencies(Action, User, FA) {
$grid = $("#grdAgencies");
$grid.jqGrid({
    url: "dhFollowUp.ashx?1=1",
    postData: {
        Action: Action,
        User: User,
        FANo: FA
    },
    height: 320,
    width: 760,
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ['Mark for Reports', 'OA #', 'Oper. Agency', 'OB #', 'Building Name','Survey Count', 'CADR', 'Select', 'EntID'],
    colModel: [
            { name: 'ab', index: 'ab', width: 45, formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false }, align: 'center', sortable: false, search: false, hidden: true},   //,  align: 'center' 
            { name: 'OANo', index: 'OANo', width: 30, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center', editable: false },
            { name: 'OANm', index: 'OANm', width: 125, sortable: true, search: true, align: 'left', editable: false },
            { name: 'OBNo', index: 'OBNo', width: 30, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center', editable: false },
            { name: 'OBNm', index: 'OBNm', width: 125, sortable: true, search: true, align: 'left', editable: false },
            { name: 'FCnt', index: 'FCnt', width: 60, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center', editable: false },
            { name: 'ab1', index: 'ab1', width: 40, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center', formatter: CADRLink},   // 
            { name: 'ab2', index: 'ab2', width: 40, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center', formatter: SurveyLink},      // 
            { name: 'EntID', index: 'EntID', width: 10, hidden: true },
    ],
    emptyrecords: "No records for this Agency",
    loadtext: "Loading Agency Records...",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: 1,
    rowList: [1,2,5],
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    caption: "Follow Up Agencies",
    multiselect: true,
    pgbuttons: true,
    pager: '#pgrdAgencies',
    gridComplete: function () {
    }, // end of gridcomplete
    onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
        if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
               && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
            $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
        }
    },
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
        MsgBox("Loading FollowUp Agency Grid: " + error);
    } //end of loadError
});      // end of grdAgencies

colModel = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
$('#gbox_' + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id) +
            ' tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column').each(function (i) {
                var cmi = colModel[i], colName = cmi.name;

                if (cmi.sortable !== false) {
                    $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico').show();
                } else if (!cmi.sortable && colName !== 'rn' && colName !== 'cb' && colName !== 'subgrid') {
                    $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable').css({ cursor: 'default' });
                }
            });

var AgencyGrid = jQuery("#grdAgencies").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pgrdAgencies", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });

jQuery("#grdAgencies").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#pgrdAgencies", {
    caption: "Toggle Search", title: "Toggle Search Toolbar", buttonicon: 'ui-icon-pin-s',
    onClickButton: function () {
        AgencyGrid[0].toggleToolbar()
    }
});
jQuery("#grdAgencies").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#pgrdAgencies", {
    caption: "Clear Search", title: "Clear Search", buttonicon: 'ui-icon-refresh',
    onClickButton: function () {
        AgencyGrid[0].clearToolbar()
    }
});

jQuery("#grdAgencies").jqGrid('filterToolbar');
```

}   // end of the LoadAgencys

There is a dropdown list that the user selects from in order to populate the grid. The grid structure display on the page when the page is opened.
this it the code for that:

```
    $('#ddlSelectFA').change(function () {
    if ($('#ddlSelectFA').val() == 0) {
        MsgBox('Please select a Fiscal Agency');
    }
    else {
        $('#grdAgencies').jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { Action: "MANAGEAGENCIES", User: $('#hdfldUser').val(), FANo: $('#ddlSelectFA').val() } }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
}); // end of ddlSelectFA change
```

I hope the above is sufficient to get an idea as to why I am not seeing the buttons even though I have (4) records and displaying 1 per page.

Thank you